# Is a newer Thunderbird safe for my Pi?

Tags: pi-3

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B+

The newest version of Mozilla’s Thunderbird in my Debian package is ESR 52.9.1 (32-bit).

Is it safe to download, install and run a newer Thunderbird directly from Mozilla?

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking ..... what do you mean by `safe`?

Comment: a) It's **not** a virus b) To install it, use this method. Open up a terminal, and type down `sudo apt-get install thunderbird`

Comment: @jsotola & user96931
Thank you for your responses.
I got T-bird by downloading Raspbian packages and then installing the updates in those packages so my T-bird is 52.9.1 (32-bit) although the most current version is 60.something. So by “safe” I mean is it okay to download a more current version straight from Mozilla or would that version not work on my Pi currently running Raspbian 9.6?